# How can I override a react-beautify setting in VSCode?

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code

I have a React Native project. In Visual Studio Code, I use the [`react-beautify`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=taichi.react-beautify) add-in to beautify my code on the fly. The add-in uses a tool named [prettydiff](http://prettydiff.com) internally.

The only thing it does that I don't like is that it condenses

```
import { Componentname } from packagename
```

to

```
import {Componentname} from packagename
```

The correct prettydiff setting to change this behaviour [is to set `brace_style` to  `collapse-preserve-inline`.](http://prettydiff.com/documentation.xhtml#brace_style)

However, I can't get prettydiff to accept the change.

I tried creating a .jsbeautifyrc file in my project's root directory, and added:

```
{
    "brace_style": "collapse-preserve-inline"
}
```

but this doesn't seem to work: the behaviour I don't want is still happening.

How do I do this correctly?

Comment: Are you sure "bracepadding" isn't the option you want?

Comment: Have you tried setting the config file path explicitly? (i.e. [`react.beautify.configFilePath`](https://github.com/taichi/react-beautify/tree/22d15d34502eb5f629dc854240d0963e0fff55e3#extension-settings))

Comment: @Whymarrh I didn't, and would prefer not to, as settings may vary from project to project. I managed to get it working using the `bracepadding` setting, see below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have VS Code in Mac v1.8.1 and if you open a Folder with a .jsbeautifyrc you could override the properties, in your example if you create a folder with 2 files:

index.js

```
import {code} from 'source';
import {otherCode} from 'source';
```

.jsbeautifyrc

```
{
  "bracepadding": true
}
```

you will get the next result after run the beautifier:

```
import { code } from 'source';
import { otherCode } from 'source';
```

Comment: Is there any way to use a global setting instead of local `.jsbeautifyrc`?

Comment: @IvanWang, Did you figure out how to do fix this globally?

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a bug,the `.jsbeautifyrc` file doesn't seem to be read in the [react-beautify](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=taichi.react-beautify) add-in.

The `settings` mentioned during the *setup* of the *addon* don't seem to work and also I have tried installing [prettydiff](http://prettydiff.com/) in my system and also the [esformatter-jsx](https://github.com/millermedeiros/esformatter/blob/master/doc/config.md) and changed the configuration but *it doesn't read the files*

**Workaround**

*You can try the [beautify](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HookyQR.beautify) add-in with the following [repo](https://github.com/HookyQR/VSCodeBeautify/blob/master/test/data/.jsbeautifyrc) here*.

and add the file `.jsbeautifyrc` to your file tree structure ,and the options mentioned in the [settings](https://github.com/HookyQR/VSCodeBeautify/blob/master/Settings.md) page work in it.

The project has been updated to the latest `js-beautify` code `version 1.6.8` with the support of the `jsx support` as mentioned in the screen shot
[image]

and also the working example
[image]

Comment: I did get it working with `react-beautify` using the `bracepadding` setting referenced by @damienfabian, so it's possible the bug you mention has since been fixed. Thank you for your effort anyway!

Comment: ohh didn't try brace padding though !